# How to increment x number of elements repeatedly y times in Python

Tags: python

I have `x` which is number of elements needed and `y` which is number of times the elements are needed.

For example:

```
>>> x = 5
>>> y = 2
>>> for i in range(y):
...  for j in range(x):
...   print j,
... 
0 1 2 3 4 0 1 2 3 4
```

Expected output is:

```
0 1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8 9
```

Can someone help me in achieving the expected output?
`for` loop or list comprehension any way is fine.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Option 1***

If you need to store the results in a list, you can use unpacking and arithmetic:

```
>>> [[*range(i*x, i*x+x)] for i in range(y)]
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
```

***Option 2***

If you're just interested in printing the values, you don't need to waste space by creating the intermediate sublists, and you can instead use the `range` objects:

```
for row in [range(i*x, i*x+x) for i in range(y)]:
    print(*row)
```

```
0 1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8 9
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use numpy. As you simply count in the range of `[0, x*y[` and just want to have it plotted in a certain shape, numpy can exactly do that in a one liner:

```
import numpy as np
x = 5
y = 2
np.arange(x*y).reshape(y, x)
```

Result:

```
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're just trying to print things, rather than store them (if you want to store them, the other answers look good). You can do it manually with this sort of loop:

```
for i,v in enumerate(range(y*x)):
    if (i+1)%x == 0:
        print(v)
    else:
        print(v,end=' ')
```

Output:

```
0 1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8 9
```

**Edit for `python 2`**: Based on your syntax error in your comment, I suppose you're using python2. Change `print(v,end=' ')` to `print v,`:

```
for i,v in enumerate(range(y*x)):
    if (i+1)%x == 0:
        print v
    else:
        print v,
```

Comment: print(v,end=' ')
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 1):

You can compose various itertools iterators to create your own generator:

```
>>> from itertools import count, islice
>>> def foo(x, y):
...     elements = count()
...     for _ in range(y):
...         yield list(islice(elements, x))
...
>>> for es in foo(5, 2):
...     print(*es)
...
0 1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8 9
```

Comment: If I have to keep `for` loop for x, let's say `for i in range(x):` then is there any way to use list comprehension only for y?

Comment: @npatel I don't know what you mean, but you can just luse `list(foo(5,2))`

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Thanks to @juanpa.arrivillaga this "range-with-offset"-idea became a serious approach in the end:

```
for i in range(y):
    print(*range(i*x, (i+1)*x))

0 1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8 9
```

Comment: this is not idiomatic: `str(list(...))[1:-1].replace(',','')`, just use `' '.join(list(...))` which is also much more efficient.

Comment: I don't get your point - I don't think that those two are equal in this case. To be clear: I tried a `' '.join(...)` based solution which did not work with my idea to just print a range with offsets.

Comment: Sorr,y, you need to replace `list` with `map(str(...))`, the point is, don't generate a string representation of a list just to slice it and replace the commas.

Comment: And for just printing, you can just do: `print(*range(i*x, (i+1)*x))`

Comment: `map` is not an option here - I would have to `list(map(...))` again to be able to print it... ugly. However: please note that I already posted my original idea below - i'd stick with `numpy`. This here was created only after I saw that people optimized about printing.

Comment: You don't have to `list(map(...))` again, just `print(' '.join(map(str, (range(i*x, (i+1)*x)))))`

Comment: Or again, if you just want to print it, `print(*range(i*x, (i+1)*x))`

Comment: And so _this_ (`print(*range(i*x, (i+1)*x))`) is really a very good and constructive hint, thank you